# Can I run PMD analysis in a Junit test?

Tags: java, junit, ant, pmd

I would like to create an automated junit test that passes if my code meets the requirements specified by PMD, and fails if it does not. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe something like https://github.com/corgrath/JUnit-PMD-Test-Wrapper is what you are looking for?

Comment: Something like that would work, but I'd probably need something that's been updates more recently.

Comment: Well it at least answers your question. It is possible and potentially gives you are starting point.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible tu run a PMD analysis in a JUnit test. However, there exist PMD plugins for every Java IDE, build and CI tool out there. Are you sure they don't already do what you want to achieve?

If you still want to do it yourself, take a look at the class PMD. It has the static method [PMD.doPMD(configuration)](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/pmd_releases/5.5.0/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/PMD.java#L230) which starts the analysis.

The same class also contains the [main method](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/pmd_releases/5.5.0/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/PMD.java#L473) in case you want to start it like from the command line.